# I want to find multiple output based of 2 given conditions in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-365

[image]

I have a dummy data for origin and destination, I want to find list of cities as text which are 4 hrs. of destination. It should give me a list of cities when I change the origin. Can this be done easily by doing some lookup and match function?

Comment: From Delhi to Kolkata is 6 hours, in the other way it's only 4 (or vice versa), is that correct?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I read this left to right (origin- destination), like revers "L", should give the output of city names which are under 4 hrs. of drive, excluding the 0,  I have updated the screen shot.

Comment: One way is to use sql queries in Excel

Comment: I am not sure on how sql will work, was thinking if this can be done easily by doing some lookup and match function?

Comment: Hi please kindly @others if they are not OP. I didn't get a notification.

Comment: [Tutorial 1](https://analystcave.com/create-microsoft-query-excel-excel-query/)
Vlookup match and if statements would leave blank lines instead of having everything neatly written together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: indian cities]

The value to lookup is in `A8`, and this is matched to the first column:

```
=XMATCH(A8,A2:A6)
```

Then return this row from the numerical data using `INDEX` (`A10`):

```
=INDEX(B2:F6,A9,)
```

The last comma is needed to return the entire row.

`FILTER` this to return only the values greater than `B8` (the criteria) (`A11`):

```
=FILTER(A10#,A10#>=B8)
```

Then multi-match using `XLOOKUP` (`A12`):

```
=XLOOKUP(A11#,A10#,B1:F1)
```

Put it all together using `LET` to save space (`A14`):

```
=LET(A,INDEX(B2:F6,A9,),XLOOKUP(FILTER(A,A>=B8),A,B1:F1))
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is working as expected.  Appreciate your quick help on this. Thanks to other also who commented and given input. cheers!